# Accidentally killed eileen the crow. Can I still get the hunter rune?

Tags: bloodborne

Is there any other place to get a stamina recovery boost rune like maybe in a chalice dungeon?

Comment: I can tell you that I have a +10% stamina rune and haven't come across Eileen the Crow yet.

Answer (score 2):

You get another chance on NewGame+.

A Version of the Anti-Clockwise Metamorphosis rune might be a replacement:

1. Max Stamina (+10%)
   Forbidden Woods on a corpse near the blue aliens.
2. Max Stamina (+15%)
   Talk to Patches the Spider in Lecture Halls by using the ladder from the second floor. Either option will produce the Rune.
3. Boosts Max Stamina (+20%)
   Lower Ailing Loran Root Chalice

Besides that, there a no other runes affecting stamina or stamina recovery.

Answer (score 1):

No I did the same thing and accidentally killed her, her rune is a covenant rune so the only way to get it is to beat her quest line and join her covenant, the hunters. I don't know of any other runes that also give +15% or more stamina.